# Created a function that calculates fib of some number and now I want to add all them to a list

Tags: haskell

So I created this function to calculate the fib of some number, pretty standard:

```
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib x = fib(x-1) + fib(x-2)
```

But now I want to be able to calculate the fib up to some number and add each of those answers to a list. For example, if I were to calculate the fib up 6 then I should get a list of [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]

Comment: A spectacularly inefficient solution would be: `fibSum = map fib . enumFromTo 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good solution

```
fibs :: [Integer]
fibs = 0:1:zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

but if we improve on your solution we get:

```
fib :: Integer -> Integer
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib(n-1) + fib (n-2)

fibs :: [Integer]
fibs = fmap fib [0..]
```

which is way less efficient than the first solution.

Answer (score 4):

The `fibs` version in @milad zahedi's answer is a classic Haskell method for generating the infinite sequence, though it's probably too clever by half for someone just learning Haskell.  Here's another method of coming up with a decent answer.

A very standard way of generating a list recursively in Haskell is to write something like this:

```
countDownFrom 0 = []
countDownFrom n = n : countDownFrom (n-1)
```

Here, the second line generates a list by producing the next element `n` and attaching it at the head of the "rest of the list", generated by a recursive call to `countDownFrom (n-1)`.  The first line provides the base case when we reach zero, so we don't keep counting forever (assuming we started with a non-negative integer -- otherwise, yikes!).

Counting **up** needs to be handled a little differently, since:

```
countUpFrom n = n : countUpFrom (n+1)
```

doesn't have a common base case -- it depends how high we want to count.  There are lots of ways of handling this in Haskell, but a pretty common pattern is to generate an infinite list and take a finite number of elements from the beginning:

```
countUpLen n = take n (countUpFrom 1)
   where countUpFrom n = n : countUpFrom (n+1)
```

where `countUpLen 5` generates `[1,2,3,4,5]`.

With all that said, we can use a similar pattern for your Fibonacci sequence.  However, if we try to write:

```
fibs n = take n (allFibs 0)

allFibs x = x : allFibs ???
```

we run into a bit of a problem.  For example, if `allFibs 1` is supposed to generate the sequence starting with 1, it's not clear if it should generate `[1,1,2,3,...]` or `[1,2,3,5,...]` -- in other words, which 1 are we starting with?

Fixing this requires a bit of trick, though once you've seen it, it's obvious.  Let's say we need to generate the part of the Fibonacci sequence that starts `[2,3,5,...]`.  If we kept track of the next **two** numbers (2 and 3), it would be easy -- we'd spit out 2 and attach it at the head of the rest of the sequence, which would be generated by the **two** numbers 3 and 5 (calculated from 2+3).  In other words, for this specific case, we'd have:

```
allFibs 2 3 = 2 : allFibs 3 (2+3)
```

and more generally, we could write:

```
allFibs a b = a : allFibs b (a+b)
```

The interpretation is that `allFibs a b` generates "the rest of the Fibonacci sequence starting with `a` and `b`".

Then, we can write the final solution:

```
fibs :: Int -> [Int]
fibs n = take n (allFibs 0 1)
    where allFibs a b = a : allFibs b (a+b)
```

which works like so:

```
> fibs 10
[0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34]
>
```